# Getting exception on passing a message from one queue to another in mule using rabbitmq

Tags: queue, rabbitmq, mule, mule-studio

I am running a flow in mule with 3 queues(`rabbitmq`). Here is my configuration xml

```
<mule xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:amqp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/amqp" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/amqp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/amqp/current/mule-amqp.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd">
    <amqp:connector name="AMQP_Connector1" validateConnections="true" fallbackAddresses="localhost:5672" doc:name="AMQP Connector1"/>
    <flow name="putToQueue1" doc:name="putToQueue1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" host="localhost" port="8081" path="message" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <set-payload value="#[message.inboundProperties['msg']]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>        
            <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
                <amqp:outbound-endpoint queueName="test.queue1" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="AMQP1" connector-ref="AMQP_Connector1"/>
                <custom-processor class="CustomProcessor" doc:name="Custom Processor"/>
                <amqp:outbound-endpoint queueName="test.queue2" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="AMQP2" connector-ref="AMQP_Connector1"/>
                <custom-processor class="CustomProcessor" doc:name="Custom Processor"/>
                <amqp:outbound-endpoint queueName="test.queue3" responseTimeout="10000"  doc:name="AMQP3" connector-ref="AMQP_Connector1"/>
           </processor-chain>       
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Here is the CustomProcessor java class

```
import org.mule.api.MuleEvent;
import org.mule.api.MuleException;
import org.mule.api.processor.MessageProcessor;


public class CustomProcessor implements MessageProcessor {

    @Override
    public MuleEvent process(MuleEvent event) throws MuleException {
        String message = (event.getMessage().getPayload() +" "+ System.currentTimeMillis());
        event.getMessage().setPayload(message);
        return event;
    }

}
```

When I hit the url in the browser(using http endpoint), 1 message is delivered to `queue3` via `queue1` and `queue2`. First, the message is put at `queue1` which transfers it to `queue2` and then `queue2` to `queue3`.
After transferring the message to other queue, previous queue should not retain the message.
But when I hit the url second time. I am getting the below exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  org/mule/module/launcher/plugin/MulePluginsClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "org/mule/transport/amqp/AmqpMuleMessageFactory"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    ..............
```

Comment: Some version-specific issues or configuration details, maybe? I could not reproduce this exception with Studio 3.5.0 on Centos 6.4, no Maven.

Answer (score 0):

What you trying to do is to recreate already existing queue. 
Think of it as if you have `queue1` on the server and then you are trying to create this queue again. RabbitMQ doesn't know if this is a mistake or your explicitly want to do this. 
In the second case you need to pass `passive` flag when you creating a queue

take a look at here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html

> bit passive
>
> If set, the server will reply with Declare-Ok if the queue already
>   exists with the same name, and raise an error if not. The client can
>   use this to check whether a queue exists without modifying the server
>   state. When set, all other method fields except name and no-wait are
>   ignored. A declare with both passive and no-wait has no effect.
>   Arguments are compared for semantic equivalence.